# Pricing non-vanilla options on EuroStoxx50 dividend futures

Tags: option-pricing, futures, modeling, dividends

Liquid vanilla EuroStoxx50 dividend futures options quoted on Eurex are calls or puts whose expiries are the same as the expiry of the underlying futures contract.

Is there any "simple" model calibrated on such liquid dividend futures options that one could use to price calls or puts options on EuroStoxx50 dividend futures expiring *before* the expiry of the underlying dividend futures ?